# rasa nlu ner_crf not extracting any entities

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition, crf

I have successfully got my code to detect the correct intent but no entities appear even though I provided some entities in my training data.

data.json:

```
    { “common_examples”: [ 

    { “text”:“Hello”, 
      “intent”:“greeting”, 
      “entities”:[] }, 

    { “text”:“Hi”, 
      “intent”:“greeting”, 
      “entities”:[] }, 

    { “text”:“I want a recipe for my lunch”, 
      “intent”:“get_recipe”, 
      “entities”:[ 
         { “start”:22, 
           “end”: 28, 
           “value”: “lunch”, 
           “entity”: “mealtime” } 
      ] 
     }, 

    { “text”:“Can you give me a recipe for dinner tonight?”, 
      “intent”:“get_recipe”, 
      “entities”:[ 
          { “start”:29, 
            “end”:35, 
            “value”: “dinner”, 
            “entity”: “mealtime” } 
       ] 
     }, 

    { “text”:“I don’t know what to have for lunch”, 
      “intent”:“get_recipe”, 
      “entities”:[ 
          { “start”:31, 
            “end”: 35, 
            “value”: “lunch”, 
            “entity”: “mealtime” } 
       ] 
     } 
},

}
],
    "regex_features": [],
    "entity_synonyms":[]
  }

}
```

This is just a snippet. I have created 15 examples in total for the get_recipe intent. I just need it to pick out the entity of ‘mealtime’ from the message put to the bot.

My config.yml is as follows:

```
language: “en”

pipeline:

-name: “nlp_spacy”
-name: “tokenizer_spacy”
-name: “intent_entity_featurizer_regex”
-name: “intent_featurizer_spacy”
-name: “ner_crf”
-name: “ner_synonyms”
-name: “intent_featurizer_count_vectors”
-name: “intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding”
```

and this is the code I run to train the bot:

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data 
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer 
from rasa_nlu import config 
from rasa_nlu.model import Interpreter

def train_bot(data_json,config_file,model_dir): 
    training_data = load_data(data_json) 
    trainer = Trainer(config.load(config_file)) 
    trainer.train(training_data) 
    model_directory=trainer.persist(model_dir,fixed_model_name=‘vegabot’)
```

This runs fine.

And the code I run to predict the intent:

```
def predict_intent(text): 
    interpreter = Interpreter.load(‘models/nlu/default/vegabot’) 
    print(interpreter.parse(text))
```

Which produces the result:

```
{‘intent’: {‘name’: ‘get_recipe’, ‘confidence’: 0.9701309204101562}, ‘entities’: [], ‘intent_ranking’: [{‘name’: ‘get_recipe’, ‘confidence’: 0.9701309204101562}, {‘name’: ‘greeting’, ‘confidence’: 0.03588612377643585}], ‘text’: ‘can you find me a recipe for dinner’}
```

As you can see the intent is correct but entities is blank [] and I can’t figure out why. I don't seem to be getting any errors. Everything runs okay apart from this!

I also ran an evaluation and got:

```
- intent examples: 12 (2 distinct intents) 
- Found intents: ‘greeting’, ‘get_recipe’ 
- entity examples: 10 (1 distinct entities) 
- found entities: ‘mealtime’ which all looks fine.
```

So obviously it knows to look out for the mealtime entity but why isn't it picking it up from my test messages?

e.g. I need a recipe for lunch, Can you give me a dinner time recipe? etc

I’m using RASA NLU version 0.14.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `ner_crf` extracts entities based on positional clues. you can try adding more examples of similiar type. e.g.

`> I don’t know what to have for lunch. 
> I do not know what to have for lunch.
> I don't really know what to have for lunch`

let me know how it goes.

Comment: @msv I've added more similar examples and it seems to have worked, thank you!

Comment: glad it worked! please make sure to promote the right answers on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

The machine learning models in Rasa need a bit of data to train. As correctly suggested in the comments, you have to give the conditional random field a couple of examples, so that it is actually able to generalize. Also make sure to vary the sentences around it, otherwise crf will not generalize to other contexts.